# Handling model state and validation in a complex view using multiple partials in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a little trouble in getting my head around how to break up my views and actions into manageable chunks in ASP.NET MVC, and I've tried searching but I'm still none the wiser.

In order to try and just get my head around this particular aspect I've created a little test project where I try to understand the situation using the example of a login form and register form on the same page. My view model for this looks as below:

```
public class LoginOrRegisterModel
{
    public LoginModel Login { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }

    public LoginOrRegisterModel()
    {
        this.Login = new LoginModel();
        this.Register = new RegisterModel();
    }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I then started with thinking about the main action.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new LoginOrRegisterModel());
    }
```

...and view...

```
@model MvcSandbox.Models.LoginOrRegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Login Or Register</h2>

@Html.Partial("Login", model: Model.Login)
@Html.Partial("Register", model: Model.Register)
```

...with partial views...

```
@model MvcSandbox.Models.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Login</button>
}

@model MvcSandbox.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Register</button>
}
```

I found that I had to make sure the properties of the LoginOrRegisterModel weren't null otherwise I got the error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcSandbox.Models.LoginOrRegisterModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcSandbox.Models.LoginModel'.

That's fine so far, although not very useful at the moment as both forms have the same field names and ids and both post back to an index page that does nothing.

HTML source:

```
<h2>Login Or Register</h2>

<h2>Login</h2>
<form action="/Membership" method="post"><div class="editor-label"><label for="UserName">UserName</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The UserName field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
<div class="editor-label"><label for="Password">Password</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <button>Login</button>
</form>

<h2>Register</h2>
<form action="/Membership" method="post"><div class="editor-label"><label for="UserName">UserName</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The UserName field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
<div class="editor-label"><label for="Password">Password</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <button>Register</button>
</form>
```

Anyway what I then looked to do, as I kind of wanted to keep the logic separate for each post, was make each form post to a different action. And this is where I think I'm going horribly wrong.

Essentially if validation fails I figured I needed to do something to try and actually build back up the model state when loading the page but I kind of got to what I have below and I'm kind of lost as to what approach I should be taking instead.

```
public class MembershipController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Membership/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (TempData["ModelState"] != null)
            ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData["ModelState"]);

        return View(new LoginOrRegisterModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something
        }

        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something
        }

        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

...with the views...

```
@model MvcSandbox.Models.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Membership"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Login</button>
}

@model MvcSandbox.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Membership"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Register</button>
}
```

The problem is because each model has fields of the same name validation is shown on both forms regardless of which is submitted, and when I've tried using an HtmlFieldPrefix I seem to get no validation at all.

Any advice on how I can break up my actions and views into manageable and maintainable chunks without giving myself this headache over model state and validation would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed approach slightly to use partial actions which seems to improve things, code below:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (TempData["LoginModelState"] != null)
            ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData["LoginModelState"]);

        return View(new LoginModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something
        }

        TempData["LoginModelState"] = ModelState;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        if (TempData["RegisterModelState"] != null)
            ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData["RegisterModelState"]);

        return View(new RegisterModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something
        }

        TempData["RegisterModelState"] = ModelState;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My index view is now:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Login Or Register</h2>

@Html.Action("Login")
@Html.Action("Register")
```

And login and register:

```
@model MvcSandbox.Models.LoginModel

<h2>Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Membership"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Login</button>
}

@model MvcSandbox.Models.RegisterModel

<h2>Register</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Membership"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Register</button>
}
```

Now to me this has the advantage over the previous approach that it actually seems to work a little more and gets rid of need for the quite frankly horribly messy idea of the LoginOrRegisterModel which may be fine for such a simple example but would get messy very quickly as things got more complex and UIs got refactored with potentially lots of refactoring of models and potentially code as well as just views.

I really get the impression some replacing of the default model binder to have some sort of model binding based on a descriminator and having the controller action working as some sort of command processor such that it would fire off the correct handler based which partial was posted would be better, and resolve the refresh issue that comes from redirection as mentioned by Mystere Man below.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a redirect, as you lose model state.  I know you are trying to fix that by passing model state in TempData, but the problem is that TempData is only valid for one access afterwards.  If the users presses F5 or hits the refresh button, the model state is gone and things are even more messed up.

In general, only use TempData for things like showing an alert or message once to a user.

Using partial views like this is always a pain, particularly when trying to post a child model to a different form, as you have found out.  The way I would do it is to use EditorTemplates instead of Partials, and then post your composite view model to both methods.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginOrRegisterModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      //  access only the Login properties, do same for Register
   }

   return View("LoginOrRegister", model)
}
```

In your view

```
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LoginModel)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RegisterModel)
```

in ~/Views/Membership/EditorTemplates/LoginModel.cshtml (and RegisterModel.cshtml)

```
@model MvcSandbox.Models.LoginModel
// Not sure why you were setting the title in a partial view, 
// particularly when you had two of them on a single page

<h2>Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Membership"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
    <button>Login</button>
}
```

The advantage of this is that it will correctly bind the parent model to the correct child model, and you can access whatever you want from that point forward.

Comment: Interesting idea using the editor templates however I still wonder about the scalability or maintainability of such an approach. The login or register scenario in this case was only a simple example I used to highlight the problem (hence not paying attention to titles or  anti forgery tokens and the like). I've played around with using partial actions rather than view, and will update the question with what I have for that but essentially I'm building something with multiple complex elements which will almost certainly be refactored several times so it's more about maintainability.

Comment: @Mark - You really do nobody any favors by not asking the actual question you want answered.  Othewise, we waste our time, and you don't get your question answered.  Ask what you REALLY want to know, not some fake example that doesn't really illustrate the problem you have.

Comment: @Mark - Well, there are numerous problems with using Partials with form fields like this.  First, notice you have the same id value for both password and username fields.  That's not valid HTML.  You either have to rename the fields, or you have to override the ID's.  It's ok for two fields to have the same name, but not the same ID.

Comment: Sorry, but I did clearly state that this was a test project and what the objectives are, and I'd tried to boil it down to only the issue in question. With any question and solution though I'd always be thinking about scalabilty and maintainability otherwise it's just not that real world practical. As for the ids that is indeed an important thing to address.

Comment: I've resolved the duplicate id using the following approach:
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Prefix = "Login")]LoginModel model)
- and -
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Login";

Comment: @Mark - Yes, that is the best way to do it if you insist on using Partials.  That's essentially what EditorTemplates do, but it does it automatically.  Not sure why you think EditorTemplates are any less scalable.  You could use EditorTemplates with the Bind syntax on the post action method, you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29811/discussion-between-mark-and-mystere-man)

Comment: Im not sure if things changed since then but TempData is available until it is read from. If you want to keep it, you use TempData.Keep()

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *can* have multiple models and partials on a single "page" and post to separate actions - this is an approach that I used in this scenario. Also I've used this with "popup" dialogs and it works fine.

Regarding models, you basically either need to have a composite model (LoginOrRegisterModel) in the "parent" view then either use that same model in *each* "child" view (just use the bits you need in each) OR you have separate child models as properties off the parent model (LoginModel, RegisterModel). These are both valid approaches which will work but I think you get better separation with the second option (2 distinct child models).

Regarding posting, I would use AJAX to perform the separate form posts and then return partial views from the controller's individual post actions in the event of an error. I wouldn't attempt to use redirect to try and re-render the *whole* page due to the kind of problems you've already found.